# How to Add a Boolean to an Array function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have the following array in pinescript that controls the output of the indicator

`array.set(sr_lines, x + 1, line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=mid, x2=bar_index - 1, y2=mid, extend=extend.both, color=mid >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor, style=Lstyle, width=linewidth))`

I am trying to figure out how to add an input.bool into this line of code to control on/off within the settings menu.

I do not see anything indicating where I can insert this function

Comment: Without the context it is very hard to help you. Edit your question and paste your entire code.

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this will do the job. You can use `array.set()` but initialize `sr_lines` with desired amount of elements, and handle `index` in `array.set()`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
addLineInp= input.bool(true, "push lines into array")
var sr_lines = array.new<line>(0)

if addLineInp and barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    array.push(sr_lines, line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index + 1, low))
    array.push(sr_lines, line.new(bar_index + 2, low, bar_index + 3, high))
```